# Multiple instances of same DBContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Good morning,

I have been working in one project of my own and I would know if someone knows if I can have multiple instances of the same DBContext in my application.

I would have 2 instances of databases that are connected in **Startup.cs** like this:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyApplicationDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("StringConnection1")));
services.AddDbContext<MyApplicationDBContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("StringConnection2")));

services.AddScoped<IAppRepository, AppRepository>();
```

This is how I build **MyApplicationDbContext**:

```
public partial class MyApplicationDBContext : IdentityDbContext<AppUsers>
{
    public virtual DbSet<Book> Books{ get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Film> Films{ get; set; }

    public MyApplicationDBContext(DbContextOptions<MyApplicationDBContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
}
```

And at last, I would like to have on my repository something like this:

```
public class AppRepository: IAppRepository
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _config;
    private MyApplicationDBContext _cntx;
    private MyApplicationDBContext _cntx2;
    private UserManager<AppUsers> _userManager;

    public AppRepository(MyApplicationDbContext cntx, MyApplicationDbContext cntx2, IConfigurationRoot config, UserManager<AppUsers> userManager)
    {
        _cntx = cntx;
        _cntx2 = cntx2;
        _config = config;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Book>> GetBookByDatabase(string book, int database)
    {
        if(database == 1)
           return _cntx.GetBook(book);
        if(database == 2)
           return _cntx2.GetBook(book);
        else
           return null;
    }
}
```

**The main purpose of this code it's to have one instance of the application that could insert and query data from 2 different databases.**

This one is the first post I've ever made, I'm sorry if I wrote something wrong.

Appreciate your answers.

Comment: The problem with this approach is keeping the two contexts in sync. When a user changes something while another user changes the same thing, which changes should be applied? Those of user A or user B? I would look for another way of doing this. Keeping it simple should always be a priority.

Comment: @LeonidasFett I don't see why both contexts need to be kept in sync, they creally are connected to different DBs and the caller is required to select the DB which is going to be used.  Anyway +1 for keep it simple, I don't see any practical benefits of doing something like this.

Comment: Ok I have noticed that the connection strings are different, so you are probably right. But then I don't really understand OP's problem.

Comment: The main purpose of this code it's to have one instance of the application that could insert and query data from 2 different databases.

Comment: What you really need to have is a scoped *factory* registered in the services collection, but I'm not sure how easily it could obtain the information it would require to decide which context to return. It may have to do a bit of nastiness to get access to request or session values if those are what should be used. (And be wary of using request values that can be manipulated by users in the browser)

Comment: if you can tell us how do you plan to pass `int database`, that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your goal is to have two databases then all you have to do is specify different database names in the two connection strings.

However, if the point is to separate the data by user, then I would say you are far better off just storing the user name in a key field in the tables.